# product details page still have product gallery issue image are not showing sometime in magento 2.4

Tags: image, gallery-image, product-detail-page, magento2.4.0

Now i added image back-end but still have product gallery issue image are not showing sometime in product details page magento 2.4

Comment: just not displaying in product details page or other places as well like home page?

Comment: product image uploaded but sometime not showing.@abdul samad abbasi

Comment: Did you look in the corresponding folder where Images are uploaded to see if it's there? I had similar issue with sample data but my images were not downloaded so I manually put them in `pub/media/catalog/product` folder and issue resolved.